# Firebase/Google Cloud Storage file security

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to figure out the most sensible way to handle file access using Google services.

Simplifying the scenario, we have

- Users (any number) that can authenticate using Google, Facebook, etc, i.e. not necessarily with Google accounts.
- Users can belong to any number of groups (equivalent to say, Slack channels), with no limit on how many users can be in a group or how many groups a users can belong to.
- Each file belongs to one group.

In an ideal (to me) world, I should be able to provide a (fast) cloud function that validates access for each request doing whatever I want. I tried that and I do have a function that does the checks (by querying firestore) and generates a short lived signed URL. It does work, but the function can be really slow to start, and even in the best scenario (no cold boot needed at all) it still takes like 400 ms which is noticeable when the files are small images that should pop up instantly.

So the next alternative is using firestore security rules. The problem I have is that (apparently) there's no way for me to check group membership anywhere (note: for us "groups" is a collection in /users/$uuid/ that contains a list of groups ids).

I considered having the groups as claims in the token, but since the claims can only use 1000 bytes, that solution is a no-go.

There's also Google groups, but if I read the documentation correctly, you can only add Google accounts to groups (I mean, to handle access directly using Storage, not firebase security).

This seems like a really standard problem to have, yet each of the approaches I've seen so far has some shortcoming that invalidates it for us.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the function yield a url to the file, have it yield the entire contents of the file.  This will shut down the window of opportunity for someone else to get a hold of that url.  The downside is that you'll be paying more for data transfer, but customized cross-product security controls aren't often cheap.

Comment: isn't there any limitation on size? Some of the files are huge (as a full movie, so several gigabytes).

Comment: I think you can send 10MB or so with CF.

Comment: so would you say the cloud function is the only solution that (performance aside) can handle the N-to-N users-to-groups relationship?

Comment: It's the only way to build rules that span products.  You can't protect files in Storage with rules from Firestore.  And you can't protect documents in Firstore with rules from Storage.  You already correctly identified auth custom claims as the one piece of data that can bridge the gap, but it also doesn't meet your needs.  AFAIK there is not a clean solution to your problem, as your requirements are out of reach of the limitations of the products.